# Execute .jar file in Spoon (Pentaho Kettle)

Tags: java, javascript, pentaho, kettle

I need to execute a java jar file from Spoon.

The program has only one class, and all I want is to run it with or without parameters.

The class is named "Limpieza", and is inside a package named:

> com.overflow.csv.clean

I have deploy the jar to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Kettle\data-integration\lib

And from a Modified JavaScriptValue step, I am calling it this way:

> var jar = com.everis.csv.clean.Limpieza;

This is not working at all, is there a way around to make it work?
Also would be nice to have a way to see the logs printed by the program when it runs.
I am not getting any error when I run the transformation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the blog below:

https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/using-external-jars-import-in-pentaho-data-integration/

Hope this might help :)

Answer (score 2):

Spoon will load any jar files present in its

> data-integration\lib

folder and its subfolders during startup, so if you want to access classes from a custom jar, you could place the jar here.

So you need to create a custom jar and place the jar in

> data-integration\lib

location.

While calling a custom class in "Modified Java Script Value" or in "User Defined Java Class step" you should call with fully qualified name. For example 
 `var jar = com.everis.csv.clean.Limpieza.getInstance().getMyString();`

**Note:** After placing the jar, make sure you restart the Spoon.

If still does not work please attach the Pentaho.log (data-integration-server/logs/Pentaho.log) and catalina.out(data-integration-server/tomcat/logs) logs

Comment: Ok, it works, but not as expected. It is executing the method when I click get variables in the step. When I run the transformation nothing happens.

Comment: Also, I don't have any Pentaho.log to see because this version of Pentaho has been deployed without any tomcat server. +

Comment: If I use getInstance method, I get the following result:                 Java class "com.everis.csv.Cleaner" has no public instance field or method named "getInstance".

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to create a User Defined Java Class (follow the guide Rishu pointed), and here is my working code:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.everis.csv.Cleaner;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    Cleaner c = new Cleaner();
    c.clean();
    // The rest of it is for making it work
    // You will also need to make a Generate Rows step that inputs a row to this step. 
    Object[] r = getRow();

    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    } 
    r = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, r);

    return true;
}
```